# Combinatorics/Probability Distribution Example Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> At a local fast-food restaurant in Oregon (no sales tax), fries, soda, hamburgers, cherry pie, and sundaes cost \$1 each.  Chicken sandwiches cost \$2 each.  You have five dollars.  How many different meals can you order?

Let's assign two groups A and B.  Let A consist of \$1 items and B consist of \$2 items.

Group A:  \$1 items:  Fries, soda, hamburgers, cherry pie, sundaes = 5 items 
Group B:  \$2 items:  Chicken sandwich = 1 item

I'm assuming this is a combinatorics problem which is unordered and with replacement (meaning more than one of the same item can be selected).  Hence there are 3 possible scenarios because of the \$5 constraint:

(I)  AAAAA:  Here we have 5 objects for group A's 
n=5 obj + 4 dividers = 9, r=5 obj

(II) BAAA:  Since there is only one B item here, I thought I could leave it out and only calculate the placement of 3 objects in AAA.  This is because I can have only one object in B, but am free to choose the distribution among the other A's.
n= 3 obj + 2 dividers = 5, r = 3 obj

(III) BBA:  Again since B's have only one item, and A is only 5 values, this group is simply 5.

So my approach is to find the combinations of (I)-(III) and add them together:

(I)  $\binom{9}{5}=126$ 
(II) $\binom{5}{3}=10$ 
(III) $\binom{5}{1}=5$

This sums to 141 but the answer is 166.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or suggest a better method?  I am using the following proposition:

> The number of unordered samples of r objects, with replacement from, n distinguishable objects is:  $C(n+r-1,r)= \binom{n+r-1}{r}$.  This is equivalent to the number of ways to distribute r indistinguishable balls into n distinguishable urns without exclusion.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have to use all five dollars? I haven't computed it, but I'd guess the remaining meals come from those totaling less than five dollars. Edit: on second thought, that might produce far too many. Maybe I'm not thinking carefully enough.

Comment: That's a good point.  I didn't think about that. It would explain the missing numbers.  Is there a faster way than going through one by one decomposing as I am doing?  It seems very tedious to do it that way, @AWertheim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For choice II, $5 \choose 3$ assumes you cannot order two of the same.  For sampling with replacement, it should be ${7 \choose 3}=35$ by the same logic you used to get $9 \choose 5$.  That increases the count to $166$

Comment: Thanks.  But when you do $\binom{7}{3}$, how can you guarantee that   you will not include more than one B?  That is why I excluded it in my binomial coefficient.  Can you please elaborate? In other words B is a special urn compared to A urns.  How do you know that those 3 objects will not get placed in 2 or 3 B urns when you include 7 in your binomial coefficient?

Comment: No ${5+3-1 \choose 3}={7 \choose 3}$ is the number of ways to choose $3$ items from group A with replacement.  It is the same logic as ${5+5-1 \choose 5}={9 \choose 5}$ is the number of ways to choose $5$ items from group A with replacement.  It is the statement in your box with $n=5,r=3$

Comment: Oh.  I was looking at it the wrong way.  I was trying to place objects from the point of BAAA.  I get it now.  Thank you Ross!

Answer (score 3):

[Generating functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=generating%20functions%20combinatorics&aq=f&oq=generating%20functions%20combinatorics&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3.4673j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) are helpful here.  You need to find the number of solutions to the equation

$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + 2x_6 \leq 5
$$

where all variables are nonnegative $(x_i \geq 0)$.  For example, to find the number of solutions to

$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + 2x_6 = 5,
$$

you should find the coefficient of $x^5$ in $(1 + x = x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)^5(1 + x^2 + x^4)$ ([use Wolfram alpha to compute the product](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%20%2b%20x%20%2bx%5E2%20%2b%20x%5E3%20%2b%20x%5E4%20%2b%20x%5E5%29%5E5%281%20%2b%20x%5E2%20%2b%20x%5E4%29%20=%20)).  You can see that the first few terms of the product are

$$
1 + 5x + 16x^2 + 40x^3 + 86 x^4 + 166 x^5.
$$

I think that the correct answer should actually be $1 + 5 + 16 + 40 + 86 + 166 = 314$ meals, and so the $166$ corresponds only to the number of meals possible when using all five dollars.

Comment: That's some crazy stuff.  I haven't got to generating functions yet but I'll have to check it out.  I'm still on chapter 1!  Thanks @Javaman.